# What is the difference between ioctl(), unlocked_ioctl() and compat_ioctl()?

Tags: linux, drivers

Going through the linux 2.6.36 source code at [lxr.linux.no](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.36/include/linux/fs.h#L1488), I could not find the `ioctl()` method in `file_operations`. Instead I found two new calls: `unlocked_ioctl()` and `compat_ioctl()`.
What is the difference between `ioctl()`, `unlocked_ioctl()`, and `compat_ioctl()`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Meta-answer: All the raw stuff happening to the Linux kernel goes through [lkml (the Linux kernel mailing list)](http://lkml.org/). For explicative summaries, read or search [lwn (Linux weekly news)](http://lwn.net/).

Answer: From [The new way of ioctl()](http://lwn.net/Articles/119652/) by [Jonathan Corbet](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/):

> `ioctl()` is one of the remaining parts of the kernel which runs under the Big Kernel Lock (BKL). In the past, the usage of the BKL has made it possible for long-running `ioctl()` methods to create long latencies for unrelated processes.

Follows an explanation of the patch that introduced `unlocked_ioctl` and `compat_ioctl` into 2.6.11. The [removal of the `ioctl` field](http://lwn.net/Articles/394724/) happened a lot later, in 2.6.36.

Explanation: When `ioctl` was executed, it took the [Big Kernel Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_lock) (BKL), so nothing else could execute at the same time. This is very bad on a multiprocessor machine, so there was a big effort to get rid of the BKL. First, `unlocked_ioctl` was introduced. It lets each driver writer choose what lock to use instead. This can be difficult, so there was a period of transition during which old drivers still worked (using `ioctl`) but new drivers could use the improved interface (`unlocked_ioctl`). Eventually all drivers were converted and `ioctl` could be removed.

`compat_ioctl` is actually unrelated, even though it was added at the same time. Its purpose is to allow 32-bit userland programs to make `ioctl` calls on a 64-bit kernel. The meaning of the last argument to `ioctl` depends on the driver, so there is no way to do a driver-independent conversion.

Comment: I was looking over the latest ioctl source and saw that the syscall does a few checks and then jumps [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ioctl.c#L43). Do you know where I could gather more information on the ioctl system? I am interested in how ioctl commands on character files get routed to the appropriate driver. Is it through `unlocked_ioctl` that this happens? The fact that a function pointer is used *per file* (in this case a `struct file`) it seems I may be close. Is the `unlocked_ioctl` registered for character files on driver initialization after `mknod`?

Comment: @sherrellbc The device driver registers the file handling methods such as `unlocked_ioctl` in a `struct file_ops` when it starts, and they are populated from the `struct file_ops` into the file object when the file is opened. `mknod` plays no role in this.

Comment: I see. I was thinking a device driver must first `mknod` to expose its interface through a character device before redirecting the associated file operations to itself (via `unlocked_ioctl`).

Answer (score 4):

There are cases when the replacement of (include/linux/fs.h) struct file_operations method ioctl() to compat_ioctl() in kernel 2.6.36 does not work (e.g. for some device drivers) and unlocked_ioctl() must be used.