# Matlab's Image acquisition toolbox doesn't recognize my webcam

Tags: video, camera, matlab

I have to work with the image acquisition toolbox in Matlab and I find it quite disturbing to always change to windows. So I installed Matlab 2010b on my Linux machine (Arch, Kernel 39). Skype & friends work perfectly with my camera (using uvcvideo/video4linux2) but Matlab doesn't. It is a built-in laptop camera and I (my user) am in the video group.

Matlab says

```
>> imaqhwinfo
ans =
    InstalledAdaptors: {}
        MATLABVersion: '7.11 (R2010b)'
          ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
        ToolboxVersion: '4.0 (R2010b)'
```

Googeling just told me, that the toolbox should support video4linux2 and that I should not run into problems if the camera can be used by other software.

It might be important, that I use Matlab 64 bit while "*lsmod | grep v4l2*" says:

```
v4l2_compat_ioctl32     8364  1 videodev
```

Does this mean that my video4linux2 driver is 32 bit?

Comment: [`compat_ioctl`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4711/what-is-the-difference-between-ioctl-unlocked-ioctl-and-compat-ioctl) suggests that the driver is in fact for 64-bit kernels to accommodate 32-bit programs, so (if that is indeed what the name means here) it's just irrelevant. It shouldn't matter that Matlab is 64-bit, but the driver could be buggy. Can you check that the webcam with a 64-bit application (`cheese`, `webcam`, `motion`, whatever you have convenient)?

Comment: cheese works. As does skype.

Comment: Same exact situation here with R2016a. cheese works, skype works, matlab doesn't.